# VSCode Can't Find the PATH To the Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I just tried to execute Flutter: New Project, but it shows an error that could not find a flutter SDK.
I've ensured to complete all of the requirements from the flutter doctor.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `Locate SDK` not Work ?

Comment: did you set the flutter sdk path ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya yup, locate SDK not work. i've been tried locate the SDK, once i restart my vscode, but it still same

Comment: As the error suggests, set up your PATH environment and then start a new shell and from it open VSCode.

Comment: I got the very same issues with @baimWonk, still don't know how to fix

Comment: "Locate SDK" and be sure to navigate to `path\to\flutter\bin`, not just `path\to\flutter`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

On **macOS** this was solved by following these steps.

First find where you downloaded the flutter sdk (Can be downloaded from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos)). It should be in your downloads folder unless you selected somewhere else.

Next:

1. Open up Terminal. Run the following command: sudo nano /etc/paths
2. Enter your password, when prompted.
3. Go to the bottom of the file, and enter the **path** you wish to add.
4. Hit control-x to quit.
5. Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.

If the sdk is downloaded into your Downloads folder, your **path** to add should be */Users/yourusername/Downloads/flutter/bin*

Lastly, quit and restart your terminal windows and VS Code. After restarting, both apps should recognize flutter and running flutter doctor should now work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Why is this not part of the flutter docs?

Answer (score 35):

If you installed Flutter extension please restart VS_CODE and try it again. I already had the same problem.

Answer (score 16):

The thing is VSCode looks for `.packages` file in your Flutter project this file contains path to your Flutter SDK & some other metadata. You're getting this error because either the `.packages` file is missing or either the path to Flutter SDK in `.packages` file contains some discrepancies.

To resolve it, you can;

1. Either edit the `.packages` file & set the path.
2. Or if you already have a working Flutter project then a `.packages` must've been already created. Copy that file & paste it in the root directory of your project.
3. Restart VSCode & run `flutter pub get`

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: This is informative. I have observed that you can run flutter projects with out having the path to the `flutter` binary in the PATH variable. This is ideal when you have multiple flutter sdks installed in your system. As a side note: This works only when you already have a project set up when Flutter was already in path.

Answer (score 10):

For Windows

1. Open **Visual Studio Code**
2. Click **Locate SDK**
3. Find your `flutter` folder
4. Click **Save**
5. Re-open your **Visual Studio Code**
6. Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`
7. Type `flutter` and choose `Flutter: New Application Project`
8. Type your project name (e.g: flutter_application_1)
9. Select a folder to create the project in

If you want to change your flutter sdk location

1. Go to Visual Studio Code > Manage > Setting (or with shortcut `Ctrl`
2. Search `dart`
3. Find [dart] configure setting to be overriden for [dart] language
4. Click Edit in settings.json

You'll see :

```
{
    "dart.sdkPath": "C:\\tools\\dart-sdk",
    "dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\tools\\flutter",
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false,
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    }
}
```

Replace `dart.sdkPath` and `dart.flutterSdkPath` with your new sdk location

Comment: "Click Locate SDK" Where is this at?

Comment: For anyone else looking for "Locate SDK", open the command palette and type it there (CTRL + SHIFT + P), select "Dart Change SDK", then you'll see the current location listed as a dropdown.

Answer (score 8):

Check your environment variables:

- Look for the `PATH` if it exists append the full path to flutter\bin
  using `;` as a separator from existing values.
- If it does not exist, create a new user variable named `PATH` with the
  full path to flutter\bin as its value.

And check the  [installation guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

After doing this:

1. Open VS Code.
2. Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`.
3. Then type `flutter` and select `run flutter doctor` it should be fixed now.
4. Create a new project to make sure it's run.

Answer (score 6):

### For Linux Users

*For future visitors :)*

I had the same problem, in my Terminal `flutter doctor` or in general `flutter` was recognized, but VSCode couldn't recognize my SDK location so `flutter doctor` for instance didn't work.

The first thing to do is to follow the steps in flutter documentation: [Flutter Doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path)

If it didn't work, change the environment variables directly.

```sh
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Now add the location of the **bin** folder of your flutter SDK, The folder that you downloaded from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/).

For example, you extracted it here: `/Home/User/Software`

Add `/Home/User/Software/flutter/bin` to the *PATH* variable. **Paths are separated by a colon(:)**

After a few solutions I tried, this one worked.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add a complementary and alternative response to the **Linux** solutions given by NoobN3rd, Traufvihal and Paulo Ravaiano.

I'm using Manjaro and for some reason my Visual Studio Code was not picking up all the environment variables definition. I tried all the solutions and finally I realised the problem was not with the variables definition (my final solution contains them all in ~/.bashrc but it should work with /etc/environment as well) but on how Visual Studio Code was launched.

In case someone else is facing this problem, I noticed that running VS Code from the applications menu fails to link the environment variables for some reason. On the other hand, launching "code-oss" from the terminal does the trick and picks all my variables defined in my ~/.bashrc file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is really the only thing that worked for me, thanks (I also use Manjaro). Most probably this is related to Flatpak and its sandboxing.

Answer (score 3):

Installing Flutter on Linux is a breeze using `snapd` as is [documented officially](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-using-snapd). But then trying to create a Flutter project by following the official steps as mentioned here - [Test drive - Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive?tab=vscode) will throw an error similar to the description provided in the question.

On a side note though, you don't have to bother adding Flutter to `PATH` if it was installed using `snapd`.

Rather, follow these steps:

```
flutter create <insert_app_folder_name>
cd <insert_app_folder_name>
code .
```

What it really does is:

- The Flutter binary is called from within `snapd` & creates a project with a directory name you provide.
- You can now `cd` into that specific directory.
- Call VSCode in the current directory which opens a VSCode instance within the project directory.

**Refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57428618/8604951) by @maheshmnj about the `.package`**. This file was created by Flutter earlier if you followed the aforementioned steps.

Answer (score 3):

**Windows**
After make sure right Flutter version is in your path: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows
and you can run `flutter doctor` successfully

in VS Code you need to go to File->Preferences->Settings (or Ctrl+,)
then search for `dart.flutterSdkPath` then click on "Edit in settings.json" make sure it is the right path there.

Comment: Its showing null here

Answer (score 2):

I would like to complete NoobN3rd information.

In VSCode Linux I used this steps:

1. `sudo nano /etc/environment`
2. Type your password
3. I added 3 paths at the end of line:

   ```
   3.1 /"flutter instalation directory"/flutter/bin
   3.2 /"flutter instalation directory"/flutter/packages
   3.3 /"flutter instalation directory"/flutter/dev
   ```
4. Save it and reboot your system

Look at my environment file to have an example:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/paulo/development/flutter/bin:/home/paulo/development/flutter/packages:/home/paulo/development/flutter/dev"
```

Answer (score 1):

This means the Flutter extension couldn't find the Flutter SDK automatically (eg. by looking in your `PATH` or a path configured with `dart.flutterSdkPath`). Clicking **Locate SDK** should let you browse to the SDK manually and record that location for the next time. If you see this again after restarting, that's definitely a bug in the Dart/Flutter extension, so please open an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code and include the output from clicking the **Show Log** button, as well as noting whether there's a `dart.flutterSdkPath` setting in your VS Code User Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. I've initially followed all the steps provided by [installation guide of Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path) and was able to run an existing project using `flutter run` command.
So I've tried again repeating the very same steps of the installation guide and changed the path that I initially set like:

`export PATH="$PATH:~/path/to/flutter/bin"`

For one like:

`export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/path/to/flutter/bin"`

Then I run `source ~/.bashrc` and restarted Visual Code and worked! so I suppose that it was something related to `~` in the path.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just installed the flutter extension, close all the vs code applications running and restart the vs code then it will work as expected.

In order to run a new flutter project,

```
Go to vs code-> View tab -> command pallette -> select Flutter -> 
give a name to the project ->give the path of the project
```

Now you are good to go with flutter.

Answer (score 1):

**QUICK SOLUTION!**: If **on macOS**, PLUS **everything had been working flawlessly previously**, and this happens all of a sudden, or periodically, here is what I eventually discovered...

**If your mac restarted**, either on its own due to a crash, freeze or overnight install of updates, and VS Code was running, it generally restores all your vscode instances, but with various environment-related errors such as this one. The reason is that you are not running in the context of a shell and you don't have access to those environment settings. See [this article from the VS Code documentation.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_resolving-shell-environment-fails)

**THE SOLUTION?**: Quit and restart VS code as you normally would. Others have mentioned this, but I thought it would be good to know **why** this happens so you aren't surprised next time.

Comment: But even when I do this, with everything the same as you said, I still have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

if youknow where have you extracted your zip file of dart(Eg. at the time of extraction i setup the path  C:\src\flutter)
then in vs code goto
c drive
-src
-flutter
-bin
-cache
-(dart-sdk)

select this folder and your
vs code will be adjusted.

Comment: Please include paths into code tags ``

Answer (score 1):

*For Apple M2 and .zshrc bash profile :*

In my case, my problem was the relative path.

I changed the environment variable

from :

```
export PATH="$PATH:./flutter/bin"
```

to :

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"
```

And all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just got out of the same trouble, after numerous hit and trials trying to run flutter commands from vs code terminal the below set of steps got the things up for me.

In Ubuntu 18.04

1. Grab the path of the directory where flutter was unpacked by you.Mine was in the **Home** directory for the root user. Location can be any of your choice.
2. Go to the Home for your root user
3. Un-hide all of the hidden files in this directory.
4. Look for **.bashrc** file. Do not look for **.profile** file.
5. Open **.bashrc** file using nano/vim/text editor which ever you like.
6. Scroll to the bottom of the file and add this line -

> export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter_linux/flutter/bin"

7. Quit all instances of the vscode (if any) opened.
8. Re-open and in the terminal type which flutter

Here -
I had re-named the un-zipped folder name like "***flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.9-stable***" with "***flutter_linux***"

Hope this helps......

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing this error, after putting the flutter sdk path at the End of the PATH variable(not in middle or start) it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to change their Flutter SDK path for the Dart & Flutter plugin

1. Click on Manage Icon(on Mac)
2. Click on Settings
3. On the Settings page, Click on Dart & Flutter.
4. Look for Dart: Sdk Path, click on Edit in settings.json
5. Edit dart.flutterSdkPath to your VSCode Flutter path

Answer (score 0):

For me non of the answers helped.
What helped was (on macOS) opening the .bash_profile file via

- sudo nano .bash_profile
- and change the path to where my Flutter was as this has changed. Or add this line `export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/path/to/flutter/bin"`

hope this helpes.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Get Flutter SDK](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk) section and locate where you have installed your **flutter\bin** folder. In my case, I put the flutter bin in my Documents folder.

See the following image [Flutter\bin location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVN5s.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution was:

take the folder where you have extracted your zip file (for example: `C:\src\flutter\flutter`) then put it in the environment variable path and restart vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Press "Locate SDK"

Step 2: Select the folder "flutter" (Browse your files until you find it, it's the default name)

Step 3: Inside the default flutter folder, select the "Bin" folder.

Step 4: Things should work out at this point :)

P.S. This worked on VS Code Editor (Windows 11)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time.  I noticed I had a .vscode directory.  I deleted (moved somewhere else) and it worked fine after that.  Probably a mismatch between my original linux vsc project which was copied to windows OS vsc.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my MacOS M2, I modify `.zprofile`

```
sudo nano .zprofile

export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin"
```

Use `Option+X > P > Enter` to save change and leave `nano`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `fvm` and apparently I've deleted the version that I'm depending on.
please check vscode's `settings.json` file and also the `settings.json` under the .vscode folder in your project, and see where `dart.flutterSdkPath` points at.