# flutter doctor fatal, unknown revision or path not in the working tree error

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get into a Flutter course and I'm getting an error message:

> unknown revision or path not in the working tree

and I have no idea what the problem is.

Here's a picture of the error I'm getting:

[image: flutter doctor error]

Comment: i think you did not set path correctly until bin, so that it is causing error. follow this ans's steps and set path again. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368899/7924072

Comment: The paths are set till bin I ve checked but it doesnt work and I tried changing the flutter channel to stable and got following error                                                                    
          "git: fatal: 'origin/stable' is not a commit and a branch 'stable' cannot be created from it"                                                                                                                                                             Can you suggest any solution from this error message.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove this from Edit environment variables. Then try to install Flutter again. Finally, you can check it by typing "flutter doctor" on cmd.