# Flutter giving errror in old sdk files although I have upgraded the sdk

Tags: dart, flutter

I created project using flutter sdk version 1.7.8. After long time when I run the build it was giving me errors in sdk files. So I just downloaded new version of flutter sdk (2.2). I have changed environment path to latest sdk version, but when I run project it still giving me error related to older sdk version.

Here is the error

> /C:/flutter_windows_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_slidable-0.4.9/lib/src/widgets/slidable.dart:786:46: Error: Method not found: 'TypeMatcher'.
> return context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher());

This is my environment variable
[image]

Why it is giving error related to version 1.78, although I have provided version 2.2 in my environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the one of the plugins that you are using is deprecated when you upgrade flutter you mostly need to upgrade the plugins as well.
and you need to change your pubspec.yaml file also and change the dart version .
so run flutter clean first.
change dart version. then try to run if it doesnt work still you need to upgrade plugins and remove the deprecated plugin.
OR 
You might have the old Path in your IDE (Android Studio, VS CODE ) ETC.

Comment: My Question is why it is still giving me error in this directory 'C:/flutter_windows_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable....' although I have downloaded new sdk and update my environment variable as well with 'C_flutter_windows_2.2-stable'. If there are issues then it must give me errors in new directory.

Comment: Its because you still have the old path in your IDE (android studio or visual code) change the path to the new DIR.

Comment: I have separate path for projects, they have nothing to do with any flutter sdk. I have added environment variable so I have create project in separate directory. When you add environment variable then you can create flutter project in any directory, you don't have to create project in flutter sdk directory.

Comment: Which software are you using for programming? 
If android studio then please do this first: Goto preferences then goto frameworks select flutter and change sdk path.
like this: https://prnt.sc/1ksy0mw
if you use VS CODE follow this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845375/vscode-cant-find-the-path-to-the-flutter-sdk
Installing flutter SDK in different path and adding it to environment variable doesnt change the path in IDE sometimes. you have to do it manually. i am 100% sure it will fix it bro.