# How to set file path error for flutter in vscode?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

The VS Code shows this error whenever I make some changes to my code in any file,
I always save the file and then create a new build but this output message pops up.
I have tried changing my directories too and restarted the projects and system too but this remains constant.[inavlid file path error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJMqS.png)

Comment: Can you post how you specified the file path

Comment: refere here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845375/vscode-cant-find-the-path-to-the-flutter-sdk

Comment: Checkout these options:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68068847/3410660

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3065

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode Can't Find the PATH To the Flutter SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845375/vscode-cant-find-the-path-to-the-flutter-sdk)