# Can’t install flutter on macOS

Tags: flutter, dart, installation, project

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro and I tried to download flutter as steps followed on the website but when I would try to run it in the terminal it would say “command not found” and I really need to start working on my project so I downloaded it as an extension on vs code. But my question is can anyone help me solve my issue and if not is it okay if I make a whole app using just the extension?

Already put in description

Comment: Double check your PATH:  https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Download flutter application and put into a specific folder like
"Developer Sdk"

Step 2:  run this command in the terminal

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/hemantpatel/Development/flutter/bin"
```

(Change your path accordingly where flutter sdk stored)

Step 3: vs code terminal also run above command.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hemantvc pointer out, the flutter sdk path has probably not been added to the system `PATH`, that's why the terminal is reporting the `command not found` when you try to run a `flutter doctor` command, I guess?

You do need Flutter SDK installed on the machine, irrespective of the VSCode extension.

If you cannot find your way around setting env variables, maybe let VS Code do it for you. Try to execute the project and it should throw an issue. See this issue [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845375/vscode-cant-find-the-path-to-the-flutter-sdk) on what to expect.

Comment: okay thank you so much

Comment: I added the path and it tells me “can’t locate flutter sdk